# I have models.py file. How can I write a test for it? What to test?

Tags: python, django

How to write tests for models.py file?

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model): #new
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institute = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Email:{} Department:{} Institute:{}'.format(self.user.email, self.institute, self.department)


class Access(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    endpoint = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=(
            ('pubmed', 'pubmed'),
            ('foster', 'foster'),
            ('med_apps', 'med_apps'),
            ('mayerson_transcripts', 'mayerson_transcripts'),
            ('all', 'all')
        ),
        unique=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
         return self.endpoint


class Request(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def start(self):
        self.created_time = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'url:{} time:{}'.format(self.url, self.created_time)
```

Need to run the test in Visual Studio Code.
Also, I have seen a lot of examples for writing tests, but again got confused. It seems like I need to work on basics.

Answer (score 0):

depend on where is your logic (in django views or in models) and where actions took place, you write your tests, in example above I don't see any logic or action, I'll give you simple example, below is an example to write test on a sign up view:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.test import TestCase
from account.models import Account

class TestSequenceFunctions(TestCase):
        
    def test_signup_index_view(self):  #Test number 1

        response = self.client.post(reverse('acc:signup'), data=
         {'fname':'ftest',
         'lname':'ltest',
         'email':'foo2@bar.com', 
         'password':'1111',
         'pass2':'1111',
         'field':'something',
         'degree':'1',
         }, follow=True)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a test_models.py file - note that it is recommended to have a separate test file for views, models, apis, etc:

```
test_views.py
test_api.py
test_models.py
test_tasks.py
```

Your models are quite simple and there is nothing much that you can test. You can for example test your Request model and if the start function is changing the created_time field. For example:

```
def test_start(mocker):
    request_model =  RequestFactory.create()
    request_model.start()
    assert request_model.created_time == timezone.now()
```

You can also mock the "save" method and assert that it is being called. For example:

```
save_patch = mocker.patch('app_name.models.Request.save')
save_patch.assert_called_once()
save_patch.assert_called_once_with(params)
```

I would recommend starting with simpler example, not timezone field as I'm not sure if there is a delay the test might not pass.

You can find how to [mock objects and assert that they are called](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)
Use [Factory Boy and DjangoModelFactory](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html) to create fake objects for testing (such as the RequestFactory in the example).